# Translation value doesn't change [Magento]

Tags: magento, csv, translation

Long story short - when I change the corresponding value for translation in the `*.csv` file - no changes apply in the website. **my cache is disabled** (and I still flushed it, just to be sure, I don't know why :D ), the files are in the correct place and I am making the changes in the correct file/scope (I checked the scope of the element by inspecting it in the front end).

Anyway, it was working and suddenly it stopped... Any ideas ?

Comment: what string are you trying to translate? isn't it translated already in the db? or in a `translate.csv` file inside your template folder? the csv file is utf8 encoded? if you open it in a text editor is it correctly formatted (enclosed by `"`, separated by `,`)?

Comment: @OSdave - I am translating just simple words like "Tax" to "Something else". Yes, they are enclosed and separated correctly. It is not translated in the db. The scope of the element is in `Mage_Tax` in the `locale` pool. 
What I did for it to work is I added in the `translate.csv` file the following: `"Mage_Tax::Tax","Something Else"` but this is not the ultimate solution for me and I want to find out why the previous way didn't work.

Comment: you shouldn't use `translate.csv`, instead use the csv file inside app/locale/. There each module has its own csv file, which will be load by the correct helper

Comment: @OSdave - I know that I should use the certain *.csv file for the corresponding module, but as I stated before - it doesn't work that way.

Comment: without knowing exactly what strings you want to translate, in what context (aka the php code in the app/ folder where it is echo'ed) and seeing how it is translated in the csv I can't help you. Please edit your question with more precise information